# ¿Pruebas en proyecto ASP.NET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, poo, pruebas-unitarias

Tengo una aplicación en ASP.Net, con web forms, pero sin ningún tipo de pruebas, y me gustaría realizarlas, ahora, pruebas unitarias no me valdrían ya que, tiene muchos procedimientos que utilizan hasta 10 tablas diferentes con inner join y
el paradigma es una mezcla entre programacion estructurada y orientada a objetos, bien, llegados a este punto de descontrol de proyecto sin ningún tipo de prueba, la pregunta es: ¿Que pruebas mínimas debería realizar? ¿Sería recomendable intentar hacer pruebas de integración?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: UAT o mejor dicho, pruevas de aceptacion de usuario cuando estas lo suficientemente avanzado en un proyecto, debes de crear casos de uso por cada implementacion que hayas realizado y probar cada caso de uso. que es un caso de uso? es cualquier tipo de operacion efectuada por el usuario, cada caso de uso tiene al menos un caso de prueba y un resultado esperado. es importante que el UAT son los casos de prueva para la liveracion del proyecto, si haces alguna modificacion despues del UAT, deberas repetir TODOS los casos de prueva para validar que no haya ocurrido ningun otro impacto en tu ultimo

Comment: Gracias actualmente es lo que se esta realizando, pero yo me refería a pruebas automáticas que puedan ejecutar los desarrolladores de manera rápida con el VS o similar

Comment: Pruebas unitarias y peer review